# angular call directive function from parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have 2 directives, 1 directive is a tooltip with content and i have another directive on an upper level of html which see if i hover on that element to open the tooltip, now i want this parent directive, when i hover on the element where it's applied, to call a function inside the child directive , which will check if the tooltip has space to go top or other wise it will open to the bottom.

So far i tried this

```
.directive('upDown', function() {
    return function(scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('mouseenter', function() {
        scope.$broadcast('setPos');
      });
    };
  })
```

This is the parent directive which see if i hover on an element and tryes to send a broadcast to the child directive.

```
.directive('contentTooltip', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      require: '^updown',
      link: function(scope, elem) {

        var calculatePos = function() {
          var scrollTop = this.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
          var windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;
          var elementOffset = elem.offset().top;
          var elementHeight = elem[0].offsetHeight;
          console.log('scrollTop = ' + scrollTop + ' & windowHeight = ' + windowHeight + ' & elementOffset = ' + elementOffset + ' & elementHeight = ' + elementHeight);
          if (scrollTop + windowHeight < elementOffset + elementHeight) {
            elem.addClass('icon-bottom');
          }
          else {
            elem.removeClass('icon-bottom');
          }
        };

        scope.$on('setPos', function() {
          alert('abc');
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

This is the child directive that i want to receive the broadcast, but it doesnt work :(

Is there any other way to access the child directives from a parent directive ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the scope of any element in angular by DOM reference of that element. In your case try this,

```
angular.element(".content-tooltip").scope();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of achieving this is through a directive controller. See the docs:

[Creating directives that communicate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use controllers. Here is a great explanation:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication